# ReferenceError Cannot find variable createXMLHTTPRequestObject

Tags: javascript

I have a simple input box with a submit button which, when clicked, makes an XHR request to a server-side PHP for some information. In its simplest form, the markup looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="word" class="form-control input-lg lookup-field" placeholder="Enter a Spanish or English word" oninput="deleteicon();" required>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-brown lookup-submit" type="submit" id="lookup">Lookup</button>
```

The button's onclick event triggers a function that performs the XHR request:

```
$('#lookup').click(function(){ testlookup($('#word').val()); return(false); });
```

The **testlookup()** function is as below:

```
function testlookup(lookupword){
    var mean = document.getElementById('meaning');
    var waittext = '<div id="loading text-center"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>';
    var hr = createXMLHTTPRequestObject();
    var url = '/assets/engines/dictengine.php';
    var vars = "lookup_word=" + lookupword;
    document.getElementById('word').value = lookupword;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            mean.innerHTML = return_data;
        else if(hr.status == 500){ mean.innerHTML = "Something went wrong! Please try again later..."; }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    mean.innerHTML = waittext;
}
```

I fail to see why this should ever refuse to work and would really appreciate some help seeing the issue. Every time I enter a value in the input box and click the button, the console briefly flashes a "*Can't find variable createXMLHTTPRequestObject*" error before the browser proceeds to refresh the page with a "?" appended to the URL. What could be the issue here and also why is the "?" getting appended to the URL if I have duly terminated my onclick function with a **return(false)** statement?

The code is implemented at peppyburro.com/test-dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a function named `createXMLHTTPRequestObject`, but it doesn't exist. The JS throws an exception and never reaches the `return (false)` statement.